# Alternative to Keepass (too often conflicts)

Tags: password, sync, nextcloud, keepass

Up to now I use Keepass and sync it via Nextcloud.

But I get this too often:

[image: keepass-nextcloud-conflict]

Translation of the error message:

> server version downloaded, local copy renamed and not uploaded

There is a conflict.

Now I am looking for an alternative to solution.

Required features:

- open source
- sync to Ubuntu Linux
- sync to Android
- sync to Mac/iPhone would be nice (optional)
- No conflicts if I edit different entries on two devices
- GUI interface (command-line only is not a solution)

Comment: Could be rather a Nextclaus issue than a Keepass issue. Are you also modifying the keepass file from another device?

Comment: @vanadium the issue is with the way keepass works. It stores all password in one file. This means conflicts will happen again and again.  I am looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: Conflicts happen if the file is changed in two different places at a similar moment - sync then is not able to tell which change should prevail. Indeed, the risk you modify the same file at the same place would decrease if each password was stored in a separate file. You would need a system that explicitly can handle and reconcile multiple edits from different sources.

Comment: @vanadium thank you for explaining the root cause of my question. The question is now how to solve it. Which tool can handle this better than the combination of keepass and some file-syncing service?

Comment: If I knew, I 'd written an answer ;)